# .net standard library with dylib - DllNotFoundException

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a dylib (`libextern.dylib`) that I've created which contains the following:

```
int extern_test()
{
    return 123;
}
```

I have a library which targets netstandard1.5 and net451 and which contains:

```
[DllImport("libextern.dylib", EntryPoint="extern_test")]
public static extern int ExternTest();
```

Finally, I have a .net core CLI app which calls the library's `ExternTest()`.  It has a project reference to the library:

```
"dependencies" : {
  "MyLibrary": {
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "target": "project"
  }
}
```

If I place libextern.dylib into the root of the CLI project then ExternTest() returns `123` as expected.

Rather than putting it into my CLI project, I want to include `libextern.dylib` within my library.  I have followed the [How to Use Native Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-use-native-dependencies) instructions as well (as various other guides which I believe have become out of date with rc2) but I get a `DllNotFoundException` when calling `ExternTest()`.

The library's `project.json` contains:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "allowUnsafe": true
},
"packOptions": {
  "files": {
    "mappings": {
      "runtimes/osx/native/": "libextern.dylib"
    }
  }
}
```

The [How to Use Native Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-use-native-dependencies) instructions omit `"mappings"` but I have tried both ways and found it was required for `libextern.dylib` to be included in the nuget package.

I have also tried packaging `libextern.dylib` into another package (Option 2 in the [How to Use Native Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-use-native-dependencies) instructions) but this did not work for me either.

What might I be doing wrong here?  Might this actually be an issue with .net core rc2?

**Update:** Tested with .Net Core 1.0 and the behaviour is the same.

**Update 2:** I've logged this as an issue on the [.Net Core github project](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/181) in case it is a problem with .Net Core or the docs.

Comment: I'm trying to use `mappings` to copy files to the root of my output directory and having no joy. `mappings` works only if I specify a directory as the key, using "." or "/" to indicate the current directory does not work. "Foo/" does, but I don't want a /Foo directory....

Comment: Hey @JayEss, could you point me to a simple example source code of this? I am trying to import a dylib as well in my NETCore project, but it is unable to find the entrypoint. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: The source code is at https://github.com/jonstoneman/nativelibrepro but 
bear in mind that this code is for .net core 1.0